# What domain is used by Opera Turbo?

Tags: dns, opera, opera-turbo

I am sure that, I have blocked the use of Opera Turbo in the settings.

The first time, opera constantly showed pop-up messages with suggestion to activate this feature. And then they disappeared, later, after one of auto updates, Opera has activated it again.

Now I disabled it again, but I want to ban for the future their servers, that they use for this function.

What domains are they using for this feature ?

Comment: could you give more details on your configuration. I would like to understand what is happening and how Opera can help you. The version of OS, Browser, and the user agent string would be useful. Also, what are the steps you have used to switch off Opera Turbo in the preferences? Thanks.

Comment: I do not want to find out, why it has changed by it self. I will block they proxy in my router.

Comment: yes but if it's a bug on Opera side, we need to know the circumstances of the issue. :)

Comment: Man, this is not a point of the question. OS Debian 6/amd64 . Latest version of Opera

Comment: Can you tell me how the turbo tag relates to your question? Maybe consider suggesting an opera turbo tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opera Turbo is using `global-turbo-1.opera-mini.net` easily findable through search engines.

Two notes:

- It can map to any IP addresses depending on the region in the world.
- It can change anytime.

Blocking the domain name will not solve your issue, **if** it's a setting bug on the side of the browser. The domain blocked, the setting in place and then your requests are going to a dead end. I'm trying to check in the Opera bug report if there is any information about your specific configuration.